# Is there a method that creates dynamic instances given the table in the step definition?

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I would like to generate a generic step where I can provide in the step all the tables that I need, including the rows and column that needs to be changed ex:

I've tried using SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic but I can't get my head around on how to then send the ParameterID or the value using different tables

```
Scenario: GS - Show Rota days usually worked on Absence form disabled
    Given the following parameter is changed
    | Table  | ParameterID           | value |
    | table1 | ShowDaysUsuallyWorked | 0     |
    | table2 | ShowSomethingelsehere | 0     |
```

```cs
[Given(@"the following parameter is changed")]
public void GivenTheFollowingParameterIsChanged(Table table)
{
    var gb = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
}
```

So I am expected to send values to different tables depending on the row I am calling, taking into account that they all use the same service

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you are asking. What do you mean by "generate a generic step where I can provide in the step all the tables that I need, including the rows and column that needs to be changed"?

Comment: Apologies for my grammar, but usually I've always had to deal with one table, so that was no problem, in the step I could've created an instance of the model that I needed. In this case the column "table" has various table names (models), so I was wondering if there is a method where I can create an instance of the table, depending on the row? Does this makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a class and use `table.CreateSet<T>()` to parse it into objects. Then you can use something more strongly typed to assist your step definition:

```cs
public class TableParameter
{
    public string Table { get; set; }
    public string ParameterID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[Given(@"the following parameter is changed")]
public void GivenTheFollowingParameterIsChanged(Table table)
{
    var data = table.CreateSet<TableParameter>();

    foreach (var row in data)
    {
        switch (row.Table)
        {
            case "table1":
                // Do stuff with row.ParameterID and row.Value to call the service
                break;
            case "table2":
                // Do stuff with row.ParameterID and row.Value to call the service
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported table name: " + row.Table);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know there is no way to create different object instances based on the table row, since all the SpecFlow table helpers return a single object or a collection of objects of the same type. Even if you could create different instances per row, you are still forced to cast each row to their proper sub class.

It will be easier to create the proper abstraction, and then use an `if` or `switch` statement to further customize the behavior.

Comment: I'd rather use reflection. Not a big fun of if stat and switches.

Comment: Even if you use reflection, you need to do something specific with each row. Unless you can utilize polymorphism, you are stuck with `if` and `switch` statements even after using reflection.